# What are some tools for password protecting a staging site?

Tags: staging

I'm using Bluehost staging options to upload a wp site that I have made locally to a test server and was wondering if there is a solution to password protect the staging/test site so only the people who employ me can see it.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has an option to protect each page's content using a password. That is done using the right panel just below/under the publish button.

However if you want to hide the entire site and make it visible only to users who are logged-in, then you should consider using a "maintenance plugin" or a "construction plugin", you can look up for those terms in your Plugins section and try one of those plugins.

Comment: Is there a de-facto industry standard among them?

Comment: There is no standard for such plugins. However you can choose the plugin that has the most downloads if you prefer to know that more users use that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

One way I have done this for an existing (not new) site is to place all of the new files in a subfolder of the main site.

Then I use an htaccess/htpassword file to protect that folder. I might even only allow certain IP addresses to access that folder.

The site URL settings are something like https://www.example.com/newsite .  I can test it using that URL.

Once ready to go live, I go into the database (I use the "Better Search and Replace" plugin) to replace all instances of https://www.example.com/newsite with https://www.example.com . Then I change the URL in the wp-options table (two places).

Finally, I set up the hosting for that domain to point the domain root to the new folder. After a bit of propagation delay, all is well.